# How find this Continued fraction $[1,3,5,7,9,11,\cdots]$ value.

Tags: continued-fractions

show this:

$$\alpha=[1,3,5,7,9,11,\cdots]=1+\dfrac{1}{3+\dfrac{1}{5+\dfrac{1}{7+\dfrac{1}{\cdots}}}}=\dfrac{e^2+1}{e^2-1}$$

I found wiki [Continued fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) also not have this problem,maybe this problem can't have simple closed form?
Thank you for you give someusefull

Comment: Your question edit makes my answer quite useless (and incomprehensible for future readers)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The entire function $g(z)=\frac{\sinh z}{z}$ satisfies the differential equation $(z g)''=z g$, or:
$$ zg''+2g' = zg,\tag{1}$$
or:
$$ \frac{g'}{g}=\frac{1}{\frac{2}{z}+\frac{g''}{g'}}.\tag{2}$$
By differentiating $(1)$, we get similar expressions for $\frac{g^{(n+1)}}{g^{n}}$, hence a continued fration representation for:
$$ \frac{g'}{g}=\frac{d}{dz}\log g = \coth z - \frac{1}{z}, $$
as wanted.

Answer (score 6):

According to [The WOLFRAM Functions Site](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Coth/10/), that is the continued fraction of
$ \alpha = \coth 1 = (e^2+1)/(e^2-1)$.

The continued fraction for $\coth z$ (with proof)
can be found in the [Handbook of Continued Fractions for Special Functions](https://books.google.de/books?id=DQtpJaEs4NIC&printsec=frontcover&hl=de#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: can you help me prove this why $\coth{(x)}=?$

Comment: @chinamath: Sorry, that is beyond my mathematical knowledge. It seems to be covered in [Handbook of Continued Fractions for Special Functions](https://books.google.de/books?id=DQtpJaEs4NIC&printsec=frontcover&hl=de#v=onepage&q&f=false).