# Exact value for the continued fraction of $\tiny 1+\cfrac{1}{3+\cfrac{3}{5+\cfrac{5}{7+\cfrac{7}{9...}}}}$?

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions

Does anyone know the exact value for the continued fraction of $$1+\cfrac{1}{3+\cfrac{3}{5+\cfrac{5}{7+\cfrac{7}{9+\ddots}}}}?$$

I [already know](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1079732/how-find-this-continued-fraction-1-3-5-7-9-11-cdots-value) that $$1+\cfrac{1}{3+\cfrac{1}{5+\cfrac{1}{7+\cfrac{1}{9\ddots}}}}=\frac{e^2+1}{e^2-1},$$ but I only figured that out by typing the decimal approximation into google of the first few terms of the continued fraction (before I knew the exact value) which took me to a math paper saying that $\frac{e^2+1}{e^2-1}$ roughly equals the decimal approximation I typed in. I then typed in the continued fraction of $\frac{e^2+1}{e^2-1}$ into wolfram alpha and it spat out $$1+\cfrac{1}{3+\cfrac{1}{5+\cfrac{1}{7+\cfrac{1}{9\ddots}}}}.$$ I have no idea how to solve these so please don't downvote, I'm just doing this in case it's useful to someone one day, and out of curiosity of course.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Note that the question you linked to is already mentioned by the OP.

Comment: Note we can rewrite as $1+\cfrac{1/3}{1+\cfrac{1/5}{1+\cfrac{1/7}{1+\cfrac{1/9}{1+\ddots}}}}$ so that $(a_{2k+1}-1)a_{2k+3}=1/(2k+1)$ for each $k\ge0$.

Comment: FWIW, the ISC [did not return any results](http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/cgi-bin/isc/lookup?number=1.2831923416922804928668988734403613957353949653725&lookup_type=smart).

Comment: But [Śleszyński–Pringsheim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Śleszyński–Pringsheim_theorem) does say that your CF converges.

Answer (score 16):

**added**
Comments point out that this post did the wrong continued fraction.
For the correct one, use $a=-1$ not $1$.  Then follow the same Satz $2$.
The result is
$$
\frac{2\;{}_2F_1(-\frac12;1;\frac12)}{{}_1F_1(\frac12;2;\frac12)}
=\frac{I_0(\frac14)+I_1(\frac14)}{I_0(\frac14)-I_1(\frac14)}  
\approx 1.2831923 .
$$

**original post**
Here is the reference for everything on continued fractions (as of 1913):

*Perron, Oskar*, Die Lehre von den Kettenbrüchen., Leipzig - Berlin: B. G. Teubner. xiii, 520 S. $8^\circ$ (1913). [ZBL43.0283.04](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:43.0283.04).

Section 81, Satz 2  evaluates

$$
c + \frac{a+b}{\displaystyle c+d + \frac{a+2b}{\displaystyle c+2d+\frac{a+3b}{\displaystyle c+3d+\ddots}}}
$$

So we need $a=1,b=2,c=1,d=2$.

Value of the continued fraction is
$$
\frac{2\;{}_1F_1(\frac12, 1, \frac12)}{{}_1F_1(\frac32, 2, \frac12)}
\approx 1.779306397
$$
This can be written
$$
\frac{2e^{1/4} I_0(\frac14)}
{e^{1/4} I_0(\frac14)+e^{1/4} I_1(\frac14)}
=
\frac{2}{\displaystyle 1+\frac{I_1(\frac14)}{I_0(\frac14)}}
$$
in terms of Bessel functions.

Comment: I am far away from my copy of Perron's book to verify, but your proposed value of $1.779306397$ is fairly different from the $1.283192342$ one might obtain from numerically evaluating OP's CF.

Comment: Checking with [the CF of ${}_1 F_1$ that I am familiar with](https://dlmf.nist.gov/13.5.E1), what you evaluated was in fact $$1+\cfrac{3}{3+\cfrac{5}{5+\cfrac{7}{7+\cfrac{9}{9+\cdots}}}}$$ which is a completely different thing altogether.

Comment: To get the OP's CF, you need to set $a=-1$, not $a=1$.

Comment: Using @Barry's correction, the expected closed form becomes $$\frac{2\,{}_1 F_1\left({{-1/2}\atop{1}}\middle|1/2\right)}{{}_1 F_1\left({{1/2}\atop{2}}\middle|1/2\right)}=\cfrac2{1-\cfrac{I_1\left(\frac14\right)}{I_0\left(\frac14\right)}}-1$$ which now tracks with the numeric evaluation.

Comment: @J.M.ain'tamathematician That is, indeed, the CF I compute here. Thanks for the correction.